# How to add bash command completion for Docker on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, docker

I am running docker and I want `bash` command completion for `docker` commands and parameters.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you have already [homebrew](http://brew.sh) `bash-completion` [installed](https://superuser.com/a/288491/231893) just install the docker completion script into the `bash_completion.d`

```
curl -XGET https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker > $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/docker
```

**Note:** If you do not have homebrew `bash-completion` installed, [follow these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/819221/how-to-install-the-debian-bash-completion-using-homebrew) to install it before you execute the line above.

**Note:** the completion depends on some functions defined in [debian bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/). Therefore, just sourcing the docker completion script as described in [completion/bash/docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker) may not work. If you try to complete `docker run` (by hitting TAB) you may get an error like `__ltrim_colon_completions: command not found`. This could mean that you have not installed the bash-completion scripts.

Comment: I have installed `bash-completion` and placed the docker completion script in the appropriate directory. But still the command completion is not working (I am not getting any error). Do I need to install `bash` too via homebrew? Or would it work with the bash included with Mavericks?

Comment: Sorry, the docker completion file was empty since the curl command failed due to a certificate error. It is working now.

Comment: The curl command works if you use -XGET instead of -GET: 




**`curl -XGET https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker > \`brew --prefix\`/etc/bash_completion.d/docker`**

Comment: I cannot get it working. I am using a Macbook and I have installed Docker using a standard .pkg file and not via brew. What am I missing?

Comment: Please look at @Hypno comment, that fixed it for me

Comment: You are probably getting the `__ltrim_colon_completions` error because you are trying to use bash-completion with the stock macOS version of Bash, which is v3.2.57 on macOS Sierra (10.12). The bash-completion package dropped support for versions of Bash older than 4.1 back in 2011. The "bash_completion.sh" script silently does nothing if the Bash version is less than 4.1. (I'm stuck with stock Bash, so I get this error too.)

Answer (score 39):

The official Docker for Mac page has a section on installing bash completion:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#bash

If you have Homebrew bash completion installed:

```
cd /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker.bash-completion
ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-machine.bash-completion
ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-compose.bash-completion
```

Comment: For those using MacPorts, you'll need to `sudo -s; port install bash-completion; cd /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d`, then go from there. You may need to set your login shell to `/opt/local/bin/bash` with `chsh` (see `man chsh`, or the discussion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366836/macos-catalina-still-uses-bash-as-the-default-shell)). Both Terminal.app and iTerm also allow you to set a non-default shell, if you're apprehensive about changing it permanently.

Answer (score 16):

The completion scripts come with Docker Beta. I want them to stay up to date. So, on OS X...

- Install homebrew's bash-completion
- Symlink the files

  ```
  find /Applications/Docker.app \
  -type f -name "*.bash-completion" \
  -exec ln -s "{}" "$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/" \;
  ```

Comment: With the advent of the new native Docker on macOS, this should be the new top answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This will be extra handy if/when they add completion for `kubectl` to the list.

Answer (score 14):

The stumbling point for me was that once you brew install bash-competion, you have to add few lines in your .bash_profile to load it once you launch Terminal:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Source: 
http://davidalger.com/development/bash-completion-on-os-x-with-brew/

Because I haven't found anywhere a step by step documentation, I've made a quick script to install homebrew, bash-completion and eventually the completion scripts for docker.
https://github.com/HypnoTheNomad/docker-bash-completion-macos-brew

Comment: @Hypno link is broken

Answer (score 7):

The auto completion of docker needed not only for mac, its also needed for ubuntu / bash terminals.

In Ubuntu

```
curl -ksSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker |sudo tee /etc/bash_completion.d/docker
```

Completion will be available upon next login.

Since its top result in google I added answer here.

Answer (score 5):

**Guide to setup autocomplete for ZSH on Mac OSX**

Follow these steps if you are using **oh-my-zsh** and **autocomplete is not working**:

**Step 1:**

*Make the following three links:*

*on Apple Silicon Mac the target symlinks should go in /opt/homebrew, i.e. replace /usr/local in above paths with /opt/homebrew*

`ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker.zsh-completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker`

`ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-compose.zsh-completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker-compose`

**Step 2:**

**Either** add `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` to `.zshrc`

**or** run `echo "autoload -Uz compinit; compinit" >> .zshrc` in your shell

**Step 3:**

Apply the change to your terminal:

`source .zshrc`

Comment: If on Apple Silicon Mac the target symlinks should go in /opt/homebrew, i.e. replace /usr/local in above paths with /opt/homebrew

Answer (score 2):

The official Docker site has a section for Command-line completion, and for Mac to:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/#mac

Helped for me with Homebrew:

```
brew install bash-completion
```

After the installation, Brew displays the installation path. From documentation is correct for me:

*/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/*

Run the script:

```
sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/1.25.4/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose -o /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose
```

Open and add following in the end of your file `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
 . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
 fi
```

Restart terminal. It's all.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be said:
if you use [brew](http://brew.sh):
`brew install docker`
will do all what you need. It includes `brew link docker` which installs the completion into `` `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/docker ``
same topic, same answer for `docker-machine`, `docker-compose`, etc. ...

else (perhaps you are using Docker Beta (new "more native" docker installation package without Virtualbox) you still have to add it manually, then follow [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132452/529977) plus have a look at the additional completion scripts for docker-machine, docker-compose and some shell-helper that are handled in the ['script' from CodeCorrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819391/529977)