# OSX autocompletion for subcommands

Tags: bash, macos, autocomplete

How can I activate autocompletion for arguments to commands e.g. when I type

```
docker im
```

I would like to have it autocompleted to

```
docker images
```

similar to what linux does (not autocomplete for the commands themselves e.g. `echo` or for filenames).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What OS are you running? BASh autocomplete for files/directories already works for me (e.g. `cd Dow <tab>` -> `cd Downloads/`) and also for commands (e.g. `ech <tab>` -> `echo `)

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132452/1369579

Comment: @Arc676 Yes your right this also works for me, but the if I type e.g. `git c` then it does not autocomplete to git clone if I press tab.
@Dorian Thanks! Now some of the commands do autocomplete